# Convert three lists with uneven length to JSON in python

Tags: python, json, list

I have 3 lists:

**filtered_headings = ['Educational Institutions', 'Number of students', 'Number of teaching staffs', 'Number of non- teaching staffs']**

**sub_headings = ['College/University', 'Basic Level', 'Secondary Level', 'Secondary Level', 'College/University', 'Basic Level', 'Secondary Level', 'College/University', 'Basic Level', 'Basic Level', 'College/University', 'Secondary Level']**

**values = ['2', '10', '12', '566', '400', '799', '355', '115', '12', '115', '11', '11']**

I want them converted into JSON in this format:

```
{
 "Educational Institutions": {
  "College/University": "2",
  "Basic Level": "10",
  "Secondary Level": "12"
 },
 "Number of students": {
  "Secondary Level": "566",
  "College/University": "400",
  "Basic level": "799"
 },
 "Number of teaching staffs": {
  "Secondary Level": "355",
  "College/University": "115",
  "Basic Level": "12"
 },
 "Number of non- teaching staffs": {
  "Basic Level": "115",
  "College/University": "11",
  "Secondary Level": "11"
 }
}
```

I get the following output:

```
{
 "Educational Institutions": {
  "College/University": "11",
  "Basic Level": "115",
  "Secondary Level": "11"
 },
 "Number of students": {
  "College/University": "11",
  "Basic Level": "115",
  "Secondary Level": "11"
 },
 "Number of teaching staffs": {
  "College/University": "11",
  "Basic Level": "115",
  "Secondary Level": "11"
 },
 "Number of non- teaching staffs": {
  "College/University": "11",
  "Basic Level": "115",
  "Secondary Level": "11"
 }
}
```

It is repeating the last 3 values over and over again, how do i get the output in intend format?

My code is:

```
result = {}
for indv_heading in filtered_headings:
    data_dict = {sub_heading: value for sub_heading,
                 value in zip(sub_headings, values)}
    result[indv_heading] = data_dict
# print(result)
json_data = json.dumps(result, indent=1)
print(json_data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can zip `sub_headings` and `values` into pairs and use [`itertools.batched`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.batched) to chunk them into groups of 3 to construct sub-dicts, and then zip `sub_headings` with the sub-dicts to produce a key-value sequence for the main dict:

```
from itertools import batched
dict(zip(filtered_headings, map(dict, batched(zip(sub_headings, values), 3))))
```

`itertools.batched` was introduced in Python 3.12. If you're using an earlier Python version, you can use the [`batched`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) recipe instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the length of the lists will grow in the future, if not, we can get a solution not suitable for production but yes to be easy, readable and understandable.

Easy not optimized solution:

```py
result = {}
for header in filtered_headings:
    pre = {}
    for i in range(3):
        pre[sub_headings.pop(0)] = values.pop(0)
    result[header] = pre
json_data = json.dumps(result, indent=1)
print(json_data)
```

Also, is it possible for you to tell us where are you getting your data from?

Because maybe there's a more efficient way to do it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution, it works for now. The length list may vary.
I am getting my data from http://nationaldata.gov.np/District/Index/112
I have to convert each table into JSON.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that, if further information is needed, feel free to ask!